# Add property to array of objects React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

I use a library that calls an API which returns an array of objects:

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  Kit.getSamples(walkingSample, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return resolve([])
    }
    this.setState({
      ActivityItem: results
    })
  })
})
```

where ActivityItem is a an empty array defined in state. Now, this will return something like:

```
[{
    "end": "2020-04-25T21:45:00.000+0200",
    "quantity": 11,
    "sourceName": "Health",
    "start": "2020-04-25T21:45:00.000+0200",
    "tracked": false
  },
  {
    "end": "2020-04-25T21:41:00.000+0200",
    "quantity": 21,
    "sourceName": "Health",
    "start": "2020-04-25T21:41:00.000+0200",
    "tracked": false
  }
]
```

This is what an API returns, and this is what is stored inside my ActivityItem array. But apart from what API returns, I need to add one more property like 'name' to distinguish different future calls. I wonder if there is any way to add some property to that array so that it will look like this:

```
[{
    "name": 'Walking',
    end ": "
    2020 - 04 - 25 T21: 45: 00.000 + 0200 ", "
    quantity ": 11, "
    sourceName ": "
    Health ", "
    start ": "
    2020 - 04 - 25 T21: 45: 00.000 + 0200 ", "
    tracked ": false}, {
      "name": 'SomeOther',
      "end": "2020-04-25T21:41:00.000+0200",
      "quantity": 21,
      "sourceName": "Health",
      "start": "2020-04-25T21:41:00.000+0200",
      "tracked": false
    }]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use map to generate a new array and add a property to each object:

```
const newData = data.map(item => return { ...item, name: 'Walking });
```